# Seg Fault raised by Shapely Concave Hull

Tags: python, shapely, concave-hull

When I attempt to create a concave hull using the below 8 points I get a seg fault. Excluding the second last point allows it to work however, and that point works by itself. It seems to be some kind of collinearity issue.

```
from shapely import concave_hull, MultiPoint
import numpy as np

concave_hull(MultiPoint(np.array([[ 584245.72096874, 7549593.72686167],
       [ 584251.71398371, 7549594.01629478],
       [ 584242.72446125, 7549593.58214511],
       [ 584230.73978847, 7549592.9760418 ],
       [ 584233.73581213, 7549593.13045099],
       [ 584236.7318358 , 7549593.28486019],
       [ 584239.72795377, 7549593.43742855],
       [ 584227.74314188, 7549592.83423486]])))
```

The point circled in red is the "problem point"
[image]

I am trying to avoid causing a seg fault

Comment: That's stuff for a bug report. I'm not deeply familiar with numpy, so I'm assuming you're not misusing their API. Even if, I'd expect to have a proper exception raised, not a segfault. So, check whether the latest version fixes that and also their bug trackers if there is any information there. If not, you already have all relevant info included here, apart from versions, so you could directly file a bug ticket.

Comment: Added a [bug report](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/issues/1873) on shapely's github. Looks like an upstream issue with GEOS. Will have to wait for a patch